# Android creating animation

Tags: android, animation

I need to create an animation around an `imageview`. The image in the `imageview` would be circular. Around the `imageview`, there will be a border as shown [image: sector 1 glowing].

Each sector in this circle will glow either sequentially or randomly as shown below.

[image] [image]

Also between each sector in the circle there will transparent gap. So, how can I achieve this type of animation. Would it be possible via `xml`(I mean creating some animation list) or shall I use `canvas`? And, since I am not much familiar with photoshop, so I couldn't created good quality images. I just pasted it from existing images.